# How to add a new row/ go to next row to a dynamically built table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, web-services, dynamic

Okay so i have a table i'm building dynamically. ATM the code i've been developing have no problem building the table and getting the data to populate the table. What my problem is however, when the table is populated with more than one row, or what's suppose to be more than one row, it just adds what is suppose to be a new row in the table to the end of the first table. So  my question is what am i doing wrong in my code, and how can i get the table to be correctly populated so that it adds a new row instead of just adding it to the first row.

My code is as follows:

```
public void UpdateTableControls()
    {
        try
        {
            machine = inputsService.GetMachineSiteDetails(SiteID);
            if (machine.ToString() != "")
            {
                foreach (Machine Machine in machine)
                {                        
                    AddNewRow1(Machine);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                logger.ErrorFormat("UpdateTableControls fail, no machine in database.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.ErrorFormat( 
                "UpdateTableControls - Exception adding either new machine type or machine model, {0}.", ex);
        }
    }
```

This gets the amount of machines that is suppose to create a row per machine. It is obtained from a DB via web services.

```
private void AddNewRow1(Machine Machine)
    {
        //start a new row
        TableCell site  = new TableCell();
        TableCell name  = new TableCell();
        TableCell type  = new TableCell();
        TableCell model = new TableCell();
        TableRow  tr    = new TableRow(); 
        Literal breakline = new Literal();
        breakline.Text = "<br />";
        Literal breakline1 = new Literal();
        breakline1.Text = "<br />";          

        //site name column
        site.RowSpan = 2;
        site.Controls.Add(AddSiteField(Machine));
        tr.Controls.Add(site);

        //machine name
        name.RowSpan = 2;
        name.Controls.Add(AddMachineField(Machine));
        tr.Controls.Add(name);

        //machine type name
        type.RowSpan = 2;
        type.Controls.Add(AddMachineTypeField(Machine));
        type.Controls.Add(breakline);
        type.Controls.Add(AddTypeComboBox(Machine));
        tr.Controls.Add(type);

        //machine model name
        model.RowSpan = 2;
        model.Controls.Add(AddMachineModelField(Machine));
        model.Controls.Add(breakline1);
        model.Controls.Add(AddModelComboBox(Machine));
        tr.Controls.Add(model);

        AssignPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(tr);
    }
```

This method creates and populates the row with data and sends it to a placeholder.

I'm guessing the problem is that i am either not adding a breakline or new line, or that it is not recognizing the method above as a new row.

Edit:

What i am trying to achieve is something like this
note | are the separation between columns.

> Site | Machine name | machine type | machine model site | machine name
>   | machine type | machine model

What i get ATM is this

> Site | Machine name | machine type | machine model | Site | Machine
>   name | machine type | machine model

no new line/row

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to add a "new line" - the break - to the cells and that's not working, or do you mean a new ROW?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you can use TableRow.  [- How to: Add Rows and Cells Dynamically to a Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bewx260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
<br/>
```

is NOT the same as adding a new row to the table.

What are you trying to do - add TWO rows per machine?  The first row containing text and the second having dropdownlists in the last 2 columns?  To do that, you'll want to generate 2 TableRow objects and add the dropdowns to the second row.  type and model would, therefore, not have rowspan=2.

Alternately, is your problem that only one row is appearing, regardless of the number of machines returned by the webservice?

Once you add these dropdowns, do you think they are going to do something interesting?  Unless there's some pretty tricky code in AddTypeComboBox that's going to do an autopostback, I'm not seeing what you're trying to do.  If you used a DataGrid, GridView, etc., you could have them data bound to a template containing the controls and it could react to a dropdownlist's changes.

Comment: the dropdowns are going to be used as a means to update the database. That part of the table works fine, what is causing the problem is that it is not creating a new row for each machine i.e my problem is that only one row is appearing regardless of the number of machines returned by the webservice.

Comment: You appear to be adding the rows to a collection of controls in a placeholder.  Does that placeholder have a table tag in it?  Could you try adding the rows to an Table object instead?

I think I see what you're thinking in adding TableRows but I'm not sure what HTML a TableRow object is going to emit without being inside a Table web control.  Check out swapneel's link to MSDN for how the Table control works.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to ASP.NET MVC and use AJAX.  All the cool kids are doing it.